# How to create a .txt file whose name is based on user input using c++

Tags: c++

I wish to create several .txt files to store information about cars. Each .txt file will store the information for one car. I will ask the user to input the car information, such as CarId, Make, Model etc. I wish to name the .txt file using CarId given by the user. How can I realize this using c++ 11?

Thank you!

Comment: It'd be nice if you offered some more concrete information on how you would populate the text files and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string filename; // string to take input
ofstream out; // Object to create file
getline(cin, filename); // Taking input for file Name
out.open(filename + ".txt"); // To create .txt file
out.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not closing the file after having opened it. Minus vote for that.

Comment: Since you edited the answer to include the `close`, and retracted your vote, you might as well remove your comment